# Unable to get Facebook profile picture using Javascript in HTML FB.api('/me'

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get Facebook profile image along with welcome with containing user profile name for my website : [www.bolbihari.com](http://www.bolbihari.com).

But only text is showing but not the picture.

This is my code :

```js
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '642539989247175',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.6'
    });

    function onLogin(response) {
  if (response.status == 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me', 'GET', {fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,picture.width(150).height(150)'}, function(data) {
      var welcomeBlock = document.getElementById('fb-welcome';);
      welcomeBlock.innerHTML = 'Hello ' + data.first_name + ','+ ' Welcome to BolBihari!';
   var welcomeImage = document.getElementById('fb-welcome');
   welcomeImage.innerHTML = "<img src="' + response.picture.data.url + '"/>";
    });
  }
}



FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  // Check login status on load, and if the user is
  // already logged in, go directly to the welcome message.
  if (response.status == 'connected') {
    onLogin(response);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, show Login dialog first.
    FB.login(function(response) {
      onLogin(response);
    }, {scope: 'user_friends, public_profile', email'});
  }
});
// ADD ADDITIONAL FACEBOOK CODE HERE
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And this is HTML code for this

```html
<div>
  <center><h2 id='fb-welcome'/></center>
    </div>
```

visit my website [www.bolbihari.com](http://www.bolbihari.com) to view the running text part of this code.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax: `response.picture.data.url` is invalid since `response` is undefined variable.

You are collecting the response from FB.api in `data` variable; so you should be using `data.picture.data.url`